# Is it possible to combine these two queries together other than using temp tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

Query 1:

```
SELECT MAX(START_DATE) AS HIGHEST_DT
FROM T;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT
START_DATE AS LOWER_DT
FROM T
WHERE END_DATE = HIGHEST_DT;
```

I'm hoping to get something like

```
START_DATE HIGHEST_DT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems you have a table `t` with two columns, `start_date` and `end_date` (and maybe more columns); you want to find the most recent (max) start_date, and then to find all the rows where the end_date is equal to this `max(start_date)`, right?

One way is (not tested since you didn't provide test data):

```
select start_date as lower_dt,  highest_dt
from   (select start_date, end_date, max(start_date) over () as highest_dt
        from   t)
where  end_date = highest_dt;
```

Comment: @Mr.Maze -  If you have a large amount of data, you may want to test both solutions and see which is more efficient. In many cases analytic functions (what I used in my solution) are faster, but not always.

Comment: Thanks, I ran against 5M recs. Your query runs a little faster.

Comment: @Mr.Maze - {:-)  Glad it worked for you, but if it was only a little faster you should leave the "Correct Answer" mark on Prdp's solution. (And in any case, at least upvote it, although the fair solution would be to leave his as Correct Answer and perhaps upvote mine if you find it helpful.) You will learn these rules over time - although the main rule, indeed, is that you are free to mark answers any way you feel is right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `Sub-Query`

```
SELECT
START_DATE AS LOWER_DT,END_DATE as HIGHEST_DT
FROM T
WHERE END_DATE = (SELECT MAX(START_DATE) FROM T)
```

Comment: I would really like to have both columns HIGHEST_DT and LOWER_DT